# WP-e-Commerce Adding A Product via Flash Button

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, flash

I have built a flash application where a user can customise a product. I currently have an 'add to basket' button within the flash application that doesn't do anything. I'd like it to add a product to the basket when clicked.

Writing a flash function with event clicks is no problem, but I'm not sure how to connect to the shopping basket and would appreciate any advice on how to do this.

It *appears* to be done in AJAX but I'm not confident in this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Dean

EDIT AFTER MILO'S COMMENTS:

Thanks Milo. Once I understand how to invoke the existing "function wpsc_add_to_cart()" I'll try to make it more efficient and implement what you have suggested, but at the moment I'm struggling to invoke the existing one from within flash.

I've determined the JQuery I need to call from within Flash is the one below, but I don't know how to call it (it doesn't appear to have a function name like I'm used to seeing):

```
// Submit the product form using AJAX
jQuery("form.product_form").live('submit', function() {
    // we cannot submit a file through AJAX, so this needs to return true to submit the form normally if a file formfield is present
    file_upload_elements = jQuery.makeArray(jQuery('input[type=file]', jQuery(this)));
    if(file_upload_elements.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        form_values = jQuery(this).serialize();
        // Sometimes jQuery returns an object instead of null, using length tells us how many elements are in the object, which is more reliable than comparing the object to null
        if(jQuery('#fancy_notification').length == 0) {
            jQuery('div.wpsc_loading_animation',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        jQuery.post( 'index.php?ajax=true', form_values, function(returned_data) {
            eval(returned_data);
            jQuery('div.wpsc_loading_animation').css('visibility', 'hidden');

            if(jQuery('#fancy_notification') != null) {
                jQuery('#loading_animation').css("display", 'none');
            //jQuery('#fancy_notificationimage').css("display", 'none');
            }

        });
        wpsc_fancy_notification(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any ideas how to call this JQuery from within Flash?

Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple function that will add an item to the cart. you could tie this to an ajax call and pass whatever POST vars you want, obviously product id, quantity, etc..

```
function my_add_to_cart(){

    global $wpsc_cart;
    $product_id = 1;
    $args = array();
    $args['quantity'] = 1;
    $args['variation_values'] = null;
    $args['provided_price'] = null;
    $args['comment'] = null;
    $args['time_requested'] = null;
    $args['custom_message'] = null;
    $args['file_data'] = null;
    $args['is_customisable'] = false;
    $args['meta'] = null;
    $state = $wpsc_cart->set_item( $product_id, $args );

}
```

Comment: Thanks Milo. I'm trying to make sure I've understood this correctly... this code doesn't go in the flash file? it goes in it's own php file which flash should activate? I was thinking before that I could try and tap into the code that is already there (replicate the existing buttons submit actions and values?)

Comment: this would be a php function that would go in your theme's functions.php or a plugin. your Flash app would call a javascript function, which would then invoke this function via AJAX. This is basically a very simplified version of the actual function WPeC uses, but WPeC does AJAX in a bad way that uses a lot more memory, it's better to look on this site for examples of proper use of AJAX in WP.

Comment: edited original question as too much to fit in comment box.